# Please explain the approach to this probability problem?

Tags: probability

A poker hand consists of 5 cards. If the cards have distinct consecutive values and are not all of the same suit, we say that the hand is a straight. For instance, a hand consisting of the five of spades, six of spades, seven of spades, eight of spades and nine of hearts is a straight. What is the probability that one is dealt a straight?

I understand that there are ${52 \choose 5}$ number of all possible outcomes.

Now, by my understanding, there are $13-5+1=9$ ways to choose any card of a suit, so that we can get 5 consecutive cards, depending on this chosen card. E.g if We are to choose triplets from $1,2,3,4$ such that they are consecutive, there are $4-3+1=2$ ways to do this —$1,2,3$ and $2,3,4$.

And there are $4^5 - 4$ ways of choosing a poker hand, for a particular set of consecutive cards. (E.g. 2,3,4,5,6 We can choose any of the four 2’s in 4 ways, any of the four 3’s in 4 ways etc. to get $4^5$, then we subtract $4$ from this value to remove the cases of all cards being from the same suit.

So the answer should be $\frac{9(4^5-4)}{52 \choose 5}$.

But the answer says that the numerator has to be multiplied by 10 and not 9.

Comment: These ambiguities always come down to the exact rules.  In standard poker, an Ace can be high or low, but not both in the same hand.  Thus $A2345$ and $10JQKA$ are both straights (if the suits aren't all the same) but $KA234$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

We cheat in poker. We allow:

$$A2345\\23456\\34567\\45678\\56789\\6789(10)\\789(10)J\\89(10)JQ\\9(10)JQK\\(10)JQKA$$

so there are a total of $10$ straights.